# Pulling Data from a POS Receipt Printer after transaction?

Tags: serial-port, external, point-of-sale, receipt, data-collection

I am working on a project for manipulating receipt data from a POS system and I was hoping you could point me in the right direction.

I am new to working with a POS system and basically I am trying to figure out how to collect receipt data before or while it is being printed and transmit that data to a tablet or another device.

What format are receipts printed in? Where can it be collected by an external device (from the serial port?!)? And any other guides or information on POS systems would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If its a COM printer you could sniff the data coming through the COM port and manipulate it before sending it on to the device.

There is software available that will allow you to do this. The data is normally just a stream of text through the COM port

The POS software I have worked on allows you to customise the receipt text so we added xml tags around the bits of data we were after to make them easier to extract from the text stream.

Comment: Okay great, I'm not trying to manipulate it but rather move it to an application or mobile device which I wasn't sure how to extract to another device (obviously manipulate the representation)

Comment: @JonHunter "There is software available that will allow you to do this" - Can you please provide links or more info on that?

Comment: @DonJunior Are you got the solution, please share it here. I'm also needed same solution.